# Temporary bound references to struct members

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lifetime, coverity, temporary-objects

I was trying Coverity out on some code base and I got a warning on a code akin to

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string name;
};

Foo getFoo();
//...
const auto& name = getFoo().name;
useName(name);
```

Is this code valid?

I had the intuition that it's indeed invalid. But then, when searching for proofs, I've come across [[class.temporary]/6.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.4), which seems to say that it's actually well-formed. Yet, Coverity issues a warning, and Coverity is surely written by some smart folks that can interpret the standard better than me.

The specific Coverity warning that's issued is

> Dereferencing the returned or out-of-scope stack pointer will access an invalid location on the stack after its scope or after the function returns.
>
> In whateverSurroundingFunction(): Pointer to a local stack variable returned or used outside scope (CWE-562)

on the subsequent *usage* of `name`. The preceding warning is that

> out_of_scope: Temporary variable of type `Foo` goes out of scope

And a sort of MRE is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/S9NXsT) (kudos to @user4581301 in the comments).

---

SO has a bunch of questions about temporary bound references, but those that I've seen each has a slightly different context, hence here comes yet another question on them.

Comment: Yes, a reference will extend the lifetime of a temporary. But this does not apply here, because you're not creating a reference to a temporary value. It really isn't. It's a reference to a member of a class that's the temporary object is an instance of. Big difference.

Comment: But, again, isn't it covered by the paragraph that I linked (/6.4)? If not, how should I read it — that is, what does /6.4 cover?

Comment: I recommend strengthening your question with a legit MCVE, something like https://godbolt.org/z/S9NXsT . I want to see how this one pans out once the language lawyers are through.

Comment: @user4581301 your example is close enough (I think), I'll link it in the question body if you don't mind.

Comment: does Coverity give a warning for the godbolt example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is well-formed. As the linked standard says, the [lifetime of the temporary](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) returned by `getFoo()` will be extended to the lifetime of the reference variable `name`.

(emphasis mine)

> Whenever a reference is bound to a temporary **or to a subobject** thereof, the lifetime of the temporary is extended to match the lifetime of the reference

The reference is bound to the *subobject* `name` of the temporary `Foo` directly, then the lifetime gets extended. Other ways, e.g. binding the reference via the member function returning reference to data member won't work.

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string name;
    std::string& get_name() { return name; }
};

Foo getFoo();
```

then

```
const auto& name = getFoo().get_name();
std::cout << name << std::endl; // UB; name is dangled
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/azkoP5A4qzPLGIrj)